# To store public folder images in state of React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a functionality where I can store a local public image of react folder in React state, after eons of trying i am not able to do it.

Is it possible, if yes can you point me in the right direction

Comment: what do u mean by "public image of react folder"?

Comment: Mean the image which i have stored in public folder of react created by create-react-app

Comment: A very imp functionality depends on it, so atleast someone tell me if its possible, coz i tried to do it,all it sends the name of file

Comment: you can convert the image into a base64 string and store that string in the state of the component

Comment: But i need to upload that too..!!! to a server

Comment: So is there any way like with blob or file Object

Comment: can u show me the image? i can guide u from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196381/discussion-between-devashish-and-alpit-anand).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the images to base64 and then use `fetch` api to convert them to `blob` to upload. something like this:

```js
var url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => console.log(blob))
```